# how hide a view controller in tab bar controller swift?

Tags: ios, swift, view, controller, tabs

How can I hide some view controllers in the tab bar?

For example, my tab bar has 3 view controllers, but my application has two types of users:

```
- user 1 can only access one of those view controllers
- user 2 can access the 3 view controllers
```

How can you hide certain view controllers, knowing Who is the user?

I have this code

```
if user1 == 'admin'
  {
    let tabone = EstadisticasViewController()
    let tab1 = UITabBarItem(title: "Estadisticas", image: nil, selectedImage: nil)

    tabone.tabBarItem = tab1
    self.viewControllers = [tabone]
  }
```

but as result i have a view black, in my storyboard view "estadísticas" have buttons, images and text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is very easy
First you need to add all tabbar items,
then just hide the tabbar index based on your user role like this..

```
if user1 == 'admin'
  {
  //Show All Tabs
}
else
{
  let indexToRemove = 3
   if let tabBarController = self.tabBarController {

    if indexToRemove < tabBarController.viewControllers?.count {
        var viewControllers = tabBarController.viewControllers
        viewControllers?.remove(at: indexToRemove)
        tabBarController.viewControllers = viewControllers
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting your view controllers depending on your User type is correct, you have a black view because you have to init your UIViewController from storyboard:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let tabOneVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Your identifier") as! EstadisticasViewController
```